# IP Address of desktop computer USB tethered to phone

Tags: usb

> For my Internet connection I use a Motorola Electrify Android phone USB tethered to my desktop computer Windows XP. My service provider is US Cellular.

I would like to know the IP address of my desktop computer so that some friends in the outside world can connect to it, like for FTP and TelNet and Remote Desktop Sharing. My phone shows an IP address (it's currently 10.244.3.92, and I realize that this will change with every power-up.)

I've been told that this is the IP address I should use, but I have not been able to make any connection to my desktop computer from outside.

Comment: That might be due to a firewall, or due to the fact that your computer doesn't run any services to connect to. To find the computer's IP address, you can use `ipconfig` (on a Windows computer) or `ifconfig` (Linux/Unix and probably also Mac). Or, from the tethered device, use the `traceroute` command (pass it e.g. `www.google.com` as parameter): the first "hop" should be your computer.

Comment: Private IP addresses are not accessible from internet: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526. If your phone has a public IP (which is not most of the times), you need to do port forwarding on phone: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220931/218526

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see the public IP of a device is by a [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?#safe=off&q=ip). If that IP still doesn't let you connect from an outside source, check the following:

- Make sure your firewall isn't blocking the connection. You can temporarily disable it to troubleshoot this.
- Make sure your computer has services/ports/servers open that you can connect to.