# Use phone as USB modem by ADB

Tags: adb, router, usb-modem

I want to use the phone as a backup line for my Linux server. Can I do this by using the ADB? I mean, forward everything to a socket and route the traffic there.

I also need some port forwarding, would be great if it could be transparent. Or do I have to use the tether option on the phone and configure an interface?

Comment: Hi, looks like you changed the question after it received an answer. As a Q&A site, please note that changing a question that invalidates existing answers is frowned upon. Also, adding a new question after it has been answered won't notify existing answers, so it'd be preferred to [post a new question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and additionally link to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure that your phone has a public IP so that it's accessible from the internet (which is usually not the case). Otherwise, port forwarding doesn't make sense. See [How to connect to Android over 3G/4G public IP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526)

Using an Android phone as a ***USB modem + router*** is rather simple. That's what we do by turning on the WiFi hotspot or USB tethering. On rooted phones, port forwarding works by adding DNAT firewall rules. On non-rooted phones, you can use `adb` or `netcat` or apps like [Fwd](https://github.com/elixsr/FwdPortForwardingApp/) (ports under 1024 cannot be forwarded though). For details, see [How to port-forward internet using Android Hotspot to PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207342/218526)

However, transparently forwarding all traffic (and not specific ports) to a Linux server - using Android as ***USB modem only*** - is complex (it won't work without root access). It works by manipulating network routing (tables and RPDB) on Android and optionally on a connected host. See [How to assign Mobile Data's public IP to a host connected on a hotspot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218562/218526)